# C# First 1 (right to left) in binary number

Tags: code-golf, tips, binary, c#

I am trying to use C# to find the index of the first 1 (right to left) in the binary representation of a number. For example, since 100 in binary is:

```
0b1100100
```

The first 1 is in the third position from the right, so it should yield 3.

234 should yield 2, 0 should yield 0, etc.

Here is my current solution:

```
k < 1 ? 0 :(int)Math.Log(k & -k, 2) + 1;
```

Any ways I can make this shorter?

Comment: The obvious tip is to remove your extraneous whitespace. I see 10 spaces that you could easily remove.

Comment: `Convert.ToString(k,2).IndexOf("1")` is what you want, or something similar, wrong site though.

Comment: @close-voters - Why the close-votes?  I think this is an on-topic [tag:tips] question.  Or have there been any rules changes I've missed in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

If only C# supported machine-specific intrinsics… There is a single instruction that can do this in x86 assembly language, and on most other processor architectures as well. Then you'd have not only the shortest code, but very likely the fastest.

In fact, making this code *shorter* is an extremely boring problem compared to making this code *fast*. There are all sorts of really neat, efficient, bit-twiddling solutions, and you could also consider using a look-up table.

None of that matters for golfing, though. It looks to me like your current solution is the best you can do. Of course, you can remove the superfluous whitespace:

```
k<1?0:(int)Math.Log(k&-k,2)+1
```

I would personally write it as:

```
k>0?(int)Math.Log(k&-k,2)+1:0
```

because I think it's slightly clearer to have the direction of the conditional test that way, as well as to compare it against zero, but I guess it's six one way, half a dozen the other.

C# doesn't support implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` like C and C++ do, so you can't really shorten the conditional test any further.

You are also stuck with the explicit cast from `double` (as returned my `Math.Log`) to `int`, as C# won't allow this to happen implicitly. Of course, that's normally a good thing because it would point out that you have a *big* performance problem here: promoting an `int` to a `double`, computing the log of a `double`, and then converting the `double` result back to an `int` will be *massively* slow, so it's normally something that you'd want to avoid. But these are the kinds of perversions you have to put up with when playing code golf.

---

I had initially come up with

```
k > 0
      ? ((k & -k) >> 1) + 1
      : 0
```

(ungolfed for clarity, of course), which avoids taking the logarithm and is therefore an improvement in code size and speed. Unfortunately, this doesn't always get the right answer, and I assume that's an inflexible requirement. :-) Specifically, it fails if the input value (`k`) is a factor of 8. This is fixable, but not without making the code longer than the `Math.Log` version.

Comment: Note that for code golf the `Math` would have to be fully qualified so your other version should be better although I haven't actually counted the bytes.

Comment: You mean the one that produces the wrong output? @the

Comment: Well you said there's a fix to it but it would make it longer. If the fix is shorter than when the OPs version includes `System.` then it should be shorter and correct.